why am i getting an error when indexing for ranges within a loop
hi pleae can someone tell me what is wrong with this code.  im counting mumber of blank cells in a range and keeps crashing out on Runtime error, overflow at line
blnkrowcount = WorksheetFunction.CountBlank(ws.Range("ay:hy"))
Code:

    Dim k As Long
    Dim y As Integer
    Dim blnkrowcount As Integer

    y = Lrow
    For k = Lrow To 1 Step -1
        blnkrowcount = WorksheetFunction.CountBlank(ws.Range("ay:hy"))
        If blnkrowcount <> 0 Then
            Sheets("Invoices").Select
            Rows(k).Select
            Selection.Delete Shift:=xlUp
        End If
        y = y - 1
    Next k
End Sub

your text
to set range by using the variable y (originally k but didtn work so tried making a new variable
Also tried & and setting a range variable all without success.

Integer maxes out at about 32,000.   How many blanks do you think are in that range "ay:hy" ?    That range has 191,889,408 cells in total.    If you can explain exactly what your code needs to do, someone may have a suggestion for how to fix it.

What's the value of Lrow and ws? Is ws Sheets("Invoices")?

Probably you should use: blnkrowcount = WorksheetFunction.CountBlank(ws.Range("ay:hy").Rows(k))

Hi Thanks for your reply, i noticed also that stack overflow is caused by int, now chaged to Long variable.  Ive tried adding the .Rows(k)) and although the code runs.  My desired outcome is to check check check cells A?:H? (8 cells) in a row and delete the whole row if any blank cells are found..

ive added .Rows(k)) to the line and altered the Range to ("A:H") as these are the columns im wanting to check and seems to work fine ill test it thoroughly.  Thnaks again

"your text to set range by using the variable y (originally k but didtn work so tried making a new variable" - can you clarify what you mean by this in an [edit]? Also, please proofread your question and remove some of the more conversational notes.

Delete Row With Blank Cells in Specific Columns

Due to the UsedRange simplification:

It is assumed that your list is the only thing in the worksheet.
Rows above the list that are not empty will also be deleted.



Sub DeleteBlankRows()
    
    ' Define constants.
    Const PROC_TITLE As String = "Delete Blank Rows"
    Const DISPLAY_MESSAGES As Boolean = True
    
    ' Reference the objects.
    Dim wb As Workbook: Set wb = ThisWorkbook ' workbook containing this code
    Dim ws As Worksheet: Set ws = wb.Sheets("Invoices")
    Dim rg As Range: Set rg = ws.UsedRange
    Dim ecrg As Range: Set ecrg = ws.Columns("AY:HY") ' columns to check
    Dim crg As Range: Set crg = Intersect(rg, ecrg)
    
    ' Validate columns.
    If crg Is Nothing Then
       If DISPLAY_MESSAGES Then
           MsgBox "All columns are out of bounds!", vbExclamation, PROC_TITLE
           Exit Sub
       End If
    End If
    
    ' Store the number of columns in a variable (if ALL CELLS)
    ' and validate columns again.
    Dim cCount As Long: cCount = crg.Columns.Count
    If cCount < ecrg.Columns.Count Then
        If DISPLAY_MESSAGES Then
            MsgBox "Some columns are out of bounds!", vbExclamation, PROC_TITLE
            Exit Sub
        End If
    End If
    
    Dim urg As Range, rrg As Range, r As Long, IsFirstFound As Boolean
    ' Combine rows to be deleted into a unioned range.
    For Each rrg In crg.Rows
        r = r + 1
        If Application.CountBlank(rrg) = cCount Then ' ALL CELLS are blank
        'If Application.CountBlank(rrg) > 0 Then ' ANY CELL is blank
            If IsFirstFound Then
                Set urg = Union(urg, rg.Rows(r))
            Else
                Set urg = rg.Rows(r)
                IsFirstFound = True
            End If
        End If
    Next rrg
    
    ' Delete blank rows (unioned range).
    If IsFirstFound Then urg.Delete Shift:=xlShiftUp
        
    ' Inform.
    If DISPLAY_MESSAGES Then
        If IsFirstFound Then
            MsgBox "Blank rows deleted.", vbInformation, PROC_TITLE
        Else
            MsgBox "No blank rows found!", vbExclamation, PROC_TITLE
        End If
    End If

End Sub

